# Why is my context in my Fragment null?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-context

I have got a question regarding the usage of context in a fragment. My problem is that I always get a NullpointerException. Here is what i do:

Create a class that extends the SherlockFragment. In that class I have an instance of another Helper class:

```
public class Fragment extends SherlockFragment { 
    private Helper helper = new Helper(this.getActivity());

    // More code ...
}
```

Here is an extract of the other Helper class:

```
public class Helper {
    public Helper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    // More code ...
}
```

Everytime I call `context.someMethod` (e.g. context.getResources() ) I get a NullPointerException. Why is that?

Comment: Looks like `SherlockFragment#activity` isn't set when initializing your fragment but injected in a later phase, thus being `null` in the constructor.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're attempting to get a `Context` when the `Fragment` is first instantiated. At that time, it is NOT attached to an `Activity`, so there is no valid `Context`.

Have a look at the [Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png). Everything between `onAttach()` to `onDetach()` contain a reference to a valid Context instance. This Context instance is usually retrieved via `getActivity()`

Code example:

```
private Helper mHelper;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
   super.onAttach (activity);
   mHelper = new Helper (activity);
}
```

I used `onAttach()` in my example, @LaurenceDawson used `onActivityCreated()`. Note the differences. Since `onAttach()` gets an `Activity` passed to it already, I didn't use `getActivity()`. Instead I used the argument passed. For all *other* methods in the lifecycle, you will have to use `getActivity()`.

Comment: @user2426316 I added an example. Both mine and LaurenceDawson's should work.

Comment: This answer also answers another set of questions: Why does TinyDB's context is Null in Fragment and also Null in MainActivity?- because you instantiate it immediately after creation!

Answer (score 4):

When are you instantiating your Helper class? Make sure it's after onActivityCreated() in the lifecycle of the Fragment.

http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png

The following code should work:

```
@Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    helper = new Helper(getActivity());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`getActivity()` can return `null` if it gets called before `onAttach()` gets called. I would recommend something like this:

```
public class Fragment extends SherlockFragment { 

    private Helper helper;

    // Other code

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        helper = new Helper(activity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the question has answered, but generally if you want to get context in fragment or dialogFragment use this

```
protected lateinit var baseActivity: BaseActivity
protected lateinit var contextFragment: Context

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is BaseActivity) {
        this.baseActivity = context
    }
    this.contextFragment = context
}
```

and in java

```
 protected BaseActivity baseActivity;
 protected Context context;

 @Override
 public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
    if (context instanceof BaseActivity) {
        this.baseActivity = (BaseActivity) context;
    }
}
```