# progress dialog not work in fragment inside async task

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

progress dialog worked fine but i use setUserVisibleHint and executed my AsyncTask in that function but after that when lunch the app, I got this error :

[image]

so i research about this and saw so many posts in stack over flow and solutions like make context or constructor inside AsyncTask but no one didn't work .

this is my fragment :

```
 public class maghalat extends Fragment {

private View myFragmentView;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DataAdapter adapter;
private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public ProgressDialog pDialog;
List<jsonContent> listcontent=new ArrayList<>();

public int dog=1;
public String url = "http://memaraneha.com;

public int id;


private boolean isFragmentLoaded=false;

public Context context;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (getActivity() != null){
    if (isVisibleToUser && !isFragmentLoaded ) {

        new GetContacts(context).execute();

        isFragmentLoaded = true;
    }
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maghalat, container, false);

    context= container.getContext();
    return myFragmentView;
}


public class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


public GetContacts(Context context) {

}

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);


        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                 id=jsonObj.getInt("pages");


                JSONArray posts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("posts");
                for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                    jsonContent jsonContent=new jsonContent();

                    jsonContent.title=c.getString("title");

                    //img
                    JSONObject post_img=c.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                    for (int j=0;j<post_img.length();j++)
                    {
                        JSONObject v=post_img.getJSONObject("mom-portfolio-two");
                        jsonContent.imgurl=v.getString("url");
                    }
                    jsonContent.pages=id;
                    jsonContent.curpage=dog;
                    listcontent.add(jsonContent);

                }

            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        pDialog.dismiss();


    }
}
```

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya its not my problem try that and not related to my problem

Comment: may be `getActivity()` return `null`. use `Context` from `onAttach` method

Comment: @kishorejethava onAttach method ? dont have this method! what is your mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem Starts From Here

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && !isFragmentLoaded ) {

        new GetContacts().execute();

        isFragmentLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

You should Check **getActivity()** **null or not** here

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (getActivity() != null)
     {
        if (isVisibleToUser && !isFragmentLoaded ) {

            new GetContacts().execute();

            isFragmentLoaded = true;
        }
    }
else
  {
     // NPE. You Must pass Context
   }
}
```

**Secondly**

Check your `onAttach` method . Pass Context here

### EDIT

Declare `Context context;` as Global .
Then put  `context= container.getContext();`  in **onCreateView** section

**Finally** , You can call **context** instead of **getActivity()**;

Comment: what is your mean about onAttach method ? i dont have this method !

Comment: @erfan you should use that .Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154905/why-is-my-context-in-my-fragment-null

Comment: can you update your code complete ? i want accept your answer

Comment: i must use context instead get activity in all section ?

Comment: @erfan nope .If you face same problem

Comment: @erfan did you solved your problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132673/discussion-between-erfan-and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: can you come in chat ?

Comment: not fix my problem at all but thanks for your try . i give u up vote and accept your answer . please give up vote to my question some people give me negative vote

Answer (score 0):

try to init pDialog in userVisibleHint();

```
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            new GetContacts().execute();


        }
    }
```

in pre exec

```
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

if(pDialog ==null)
{
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
}

        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Context`. may be getActivity() return `null`. use `Context` from `onAttach` method

```
private Context context;
...
...
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
}
```

pass `context`

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
```